# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'findById' at exports.save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have found several of these question on here, however the ones I have found deal mostly with HTML, I am having this problem on submitting of a login in java.

Very Simple Save Function

```
var model = require('../../models/User')
exports.save= function(req,res){
  model.findById(req.body.id,function(err,doc){
    if(!doc) doc = new model()
    doc.email = req.body.email
    doc.password = req.body.password
    doc.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        req.flash('error',err)
      }
      else{
        req.flash('success','User saved')
        res.redirect('/')
      }
    })
  })
}
```

my model is very long but here is a sample of it

```
//define schema
schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    label: 'Email',
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    index: true,
    validate: [
      validate('len','6','100'),
      validate('isEmail')
    ]
  },
  password: {
    label: 'Password',
    type: String,
    required: true,
    select: false,
    get: function(){ return '********' },
    set: function(v){
      return bcrypt.hashSync(v,bcrypt.genSaltSync(12))
    },
    validate: [
      validate('len','8','64')
    ]
  },
model = mongoose.model('User',schema)
exports.name = 'user'
exports.description = 'User Model'
exports.schema = schema
exports.model = model
```

Submits to the function via modal and on every submit I get the err

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'findById' at exports.save
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var model = require('../../models/User')
```

to

```
var model = require('../../models/User').model
```

Also see [the documentation on modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports).

Comment: wow, cant believe I missed that haha. Now running a loop but at least prob 1 is fixed. Thanks mscdex +1